# Is there a word for " someone who hates people from their own country"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary, epithet-requests

A xenophobe is someone who holds a strong dislike toward people from other countries.

My question is: is there a word for someone who holds a strong dislike toward people from their own country?

I mean a word based on my explanation - not a misanthrope or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Can you expand your question to include a reason why they hate people from their own country? Racism? Sexism? Different political view such as Trump vs Hillary?

Comment: @Rathony is the reason necessary?  The definition of the word seems clear enough to me.  With "Xenophobe" we don't need to know the reason why the person hates foreigners - that's not part of the semantics of the word.

Comment: I agree that it's a duplicate, though.

Comment: @MaxWilliams If you think *xenophobia* applies to every situation where people dislike all the people from other countries, yes, the reason is not necessary. But I don't think the word works that way. I should have asked for an example sentence where the word would be used. But my question is is there such a word?

Comment: *Anti-chauvinist*, or *anti-nationalist*, perhaps? I'm sure we could find an *anti-something* which works. Or we could go with *self-loathing*, as in Woody Allen's famous characters.

Comment: For countries of high ethnic homogeneity, *race traitor*?

Answer (score -1):

Kindly try to understand that there is a big difference between fear and hate.
XENOPHOBIA= 
a fear of foreigners or strangers
Type of:
social phobia
any phobia (other than agoraphobia) associated with situations in which you are subject to criticism by others (as fear of eating in public or public speaking etc)
SEE https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/xenophobia
another rather poor query.

Comment: If you check in AHDEL, ODO, Collins, CDO, RHK Webster's ... you will see that the primary definition is fear **or** hatred / prejudice / contempt of/for foreigners etc. This answer  picks a reference not in line with most, and is possibly an example of the etymological fallacy (because phobos meant fear in Greek, -phobia can't mean hatred / dislike in English words).

Comment: No, I'm saying your 'answer' doesn't give the complete picture. So I don't agree. Hence the downvote.  [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/xenophobia) is skewed the other way in its primary definition, probably because its researches find that's the sense people most often have in mind: << **xenophobia** noun [mass noun] dislike of or prejudice against people from other countries:
_racism and xenophobia are steadily growing in Europe_ >> Neither your definition nor theirs is totally acceptable;

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/xenophobia) is fine with << extreme dislike or fear of foreigners, their customs, their religions, etc.>>